# Leading zeros in datatype nchar(2) MSSQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dataset, sqldatatypes

I have a field named **mix** with a datatype of **nchar(2)** in table users. The DataSet in VS2010 was created from this table. The field mix in DataSet is of type **System.String** with maxlength set to **2**. I have a textfield which is bind to this DataSet. Now if for example I change the value to "00" and click save  I can see that when the program is updating DataSet back to the DataBase:

```
usersTableAdapter.Update(usersDataSet.Users);
```

The value of currently selected user is "**00**":

```
currentUser.mix = "00";
```

But in the DataBase the value has been saved like this: "**0** ". I don't understand why was the first zero removed and the space was appended at the end. If for example I put "10" in textfield and save, it will be saved in data base as "10". But if I put in textfield as "01", again the leading zero will be removed -> "1 ".

Comment: Something, somewhere, is converting this value to be a numeric type (and, probably, the final insert/update is converting it back into a string). You need to find out where this conversion is happening.

Comment: I debugged line by line and to the final Update code, the value of mix is always in string ("00"), so I have no idea where this conversion colud be happening. I think it happens somewhere between dataset and database.

Comment: Examine the `UpdateCommand` and `InsertCommand` on (what I presume is an `SqlDataAdapter`) `usersTableAdapter`. What are their `CommandText`s? Are there any parameters? If they are at fault, how was `usersTableAdapter` constructed?

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer. I just needed to configure Fill,GetData() and execute SELECT * FROM Users once more to update all the attributes. But here is what is bothering me. I know I made a mistake when I changed database and then went into dataset and changed attributes by hand (from decimal to nchar(2)). But should not UpdateCommand, InsertCommand and DeleteCommand respect the changes in DataSet type? Where are even this default commands defined? I cannot see them in dataset under tableadapter? Are they in designer, so that you cannot update them by hand?

Comment: Also please post your comment uder answer so I can accept it as the right one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something, somewhere, is converting this value to be a numeric type (and, probably, the final insert/update is converting it back into a string). You need to find out where this conversion is happening.

Based on your comment:

> I debugged line by line and to the final `Update` code, the value of mix is always in string ("00")

The last place to check would be to see what the commands are that have been configured for your `SqlDataAdapter` (`usersTableAdapter`). Examine the [`InsertCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand.aspx) and [`UpdateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx), and ensure that the command is sensible, and any parameters are of the correct type.

I'm afraid I've not worked much with the designer based data access, but I believe that the commands are selected when the table adapter is first created in the designer - if you want to change the shape of the dataset (e.g. change column types), I'd recommend deleting and re-creating the adapter/dataset (but hey, that's meant to be easy with the designer based tools, isn't it?)